# How do I select repeated values from a pandas MultiIndex?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large pandas dataframe which is sorted such that a multiindex saves quite a bit of space. I want to keep the efficiency of the large multiindex while selecting repeated rows in a specific order, but if I have slices in the indexers then pandas ignores duplicate values:

```py
import pandas as pd
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([[1,1,2,2,2,3,3],
                                 [0,1,0,1,2,0,1],
                                 ['w','w','w','x','y','w','z']])
multi = pd.DataFrame({'uid':[10,11,12,13,14,15,16]}, index=idx)

idx = pd.IndexSlice
print(multi.loc[idx[[1,2,1], :, :, :], :])
```

```
           uid
1   0   w   10
    1   w   11
2   0   w   12
    1   x   13
    2   y   14
```

The output I want should be six rows long, just like the above with the top two rows repeated at the end. I can get the output I want by resetting the index and merging, like this:

```py
selector = pd.Series([1,2,1], name='level_0')
multi.loc[multi.index.get_level_values(0).isin(selector)] \
     .reset_index() \
     .merge(selector, how='right')
```

```
    level_0 level_1 level_2 uid
0         1       0       w  10
1         1       1       w  11
2         2       0       w  12
3         2       1       x  13
4         2       2       y  14
5         1       0       w  10
6         1       1       w  11
```

But this requires making selectors and doing `multi.loc[]` for every level I want to select from or else resetting the index on the entire dataframe.

Is there a way to do this by slicing a MultiIndex?

Comment: You want to do something like `multi.loc[[1, 2, 1]]` ?

Comment: Would something like `pd.concat([multi.loc[[i]] for i in [1, 2, 1]])` be okay with you?

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't just do `multi.loc[[1, 2, 1]]` for some reason, perhaps you can use `pd.concat` with list-comprehension:

```
indexes = [1, 2, 1]
repeated = pd.concat([multi.loc[[i]] for i in indexes])
```

Output:

```
>>> repeated
       uid
1 0 w   10
  1 w   11
2 0 w   12
  1 x   13
  2 y   14
1 0 w   10
  1 w   11
```

Comment: `multi.loc[[1,2,1]]` gives me the error `NotImplementedError: Index._join_level on non-unique index is not implemented`. And in any case, that solution only works when indexing a single level, right? I am usually not.